# Correct expression of confidence level

Tags: statistical-significance, interpretation, terminology, confidence-interval

A very basic question: when noting the statistical significance of fitting some model, does one report that results are significant at the 95 percent confidence level, or at 0.05 significance?

Answer (score 3):

One generally reports decisions to reject or not reject in a hypothesis testing context by reporting results along the lines of "...at the $\alpha$ = 0.05 level". Confidence levels are generally reported when reporting confidence intervals, along the lines of "*result* (95%CI: *lower*, *upper*)."